# Prevent SIGKILL of a process in python on grok

Tags: python

In some programs that could potentially use lots of RAM the program is terminated by signal sigkill

I know it is possible to prevent the sigkill process using a local editor but just wondering about when the editor is online? Say, grok for example?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't generally any way to increase RAM in online editors. Online editors are generally meant to run small snippets of code. The only way to not use lot of memory is to optimize your program to not hog memory when it does not need to, but of-course this is not always possible.